# Query won't show decimal values

Tags: c#, ms-access, decimal

I have an Access query that should pull the quantity purchased in a month for a set of items. My join is set to select all items from Analysis, and items from product that match analysis.

```
    SELECT AnalysisItems.Pmid, AnalysisItems.ProductName, Sum(Transactions.TransactionQty) 
    AS SumOfTransactionQty, Transactions.StoreAccount
    FROM AnalysisItems INNER JOIN Transactions ON AnalysisItems.Pmid = Transactions.Pmid
    WHERE (((Transactions.TransactionDate) Between #4/1/2011# And #4/30/2011#) 
    AND StoreAccount = 964290)
    GROUP BY AnalysisItems.Pmid, AnalysisItems.ProductName, Transactions.StoreAccount
    ORDER BY AnalysisItems.ProductName;
```

I want to see all 78 analysis items, whether they have a quantity value or not. This only returns items that have quantities. It also does not return values that are negative or values between 0 and 1 ... it won't show me 0.50 even though I know there are some decimal values in there. Everything is set to Standard decimal, scale 2

I've tried changing to general number and getting rid of the format completely but that doesn't work either.

So my questions are: What can I try to see the decimal values in my query, and how can I see all the items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I want to see all 78 analysis items, whether they have a quantity value or not."

If that means you want AnalysisItems rows included in the result set even if those items don't have any matches in Transactions for the month of April and StoreAccount 964290, they will not be included when you place those conditions in the WHERE clause ... you'll only get the rows which match the WHERE clause conditions.

I think you need to use a subquery for Transactions and move the WHERE clause into the subquery.  And LEFT JOIN AnalysisItems to the subquery.

```
SELECT
    a.Pmid,
    a.ProductName,
    Sum(t.TransactionQty) AS SumOfTransactionQty,
    t.StoreAccount
FROM
    AnalysisItems AS a
    LEFT JOIN [
        SELECT
            Pmid,
            TransactionQty,
            StoreAccount
        FROM Transactions
        WHERE
            (TransactionDate Between #4/1/2011# And #4/30/2011#) 
            AND StoreAccount = 964290
        ]. AS t
        ON a.Pmid = t.Pmid
GROUP BY
    a.Pmid, 
    a.ProductName,
    t.StoreAccount
ORDER BY
    a.ProductName;
```

Comment: That worked beautifully thank you! The only thing I have to figure out now is.. The two dates and the Store account are selected from combo boxes in my windows form app. Usually in a query I would use ? inplace of the actual value but I get an unable to parse error when I try using the ?'s with this query. Might this have to do with a parameter setup? I shall see what info I can find.

Comment: You're welcome.  Sorry I can't help you with the parameters from Dot Net.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have a part of your query as:

```
FROM AnalysisItems INNER JOIN Transactions ON AnalysisItems.Pmid = Transactions.Pmid
WHERE (((Transactions.TransactionDate) Between #4/1/2011# And #4/30/2011#)
```

The inner join that you have specified, does not give the results that you asked for - ideally, you want to use a left join for your purpose. Replace

```
FROM AnalysisItems INNER JOIN Transactions
```

with

```
FROM AnalysisItems LEFT JOIN Transactions
```

I think it should work fine

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it's still not working. I also went ahead and tried LEFT OUTER.

Comment: Jet/ACE SQL does not treat LEFT OUTER JOIN any differently from LEFT JOIN.

Comment: If you write a query with LEFT OUTER JOIN, save it, close it and then re-open it, you'll find that it says LEFT JOIN, so "OUTER" is a waste of time with Jet/ACE SQL.